# Required Field Validation in ASP MVC using Kendo UI

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a textbox and want to display the field is required when the form gets submitted. The error message do appear in case i click on the textbox and tab to go to next textbox. I have the 'Required' data annotation on my model like this:

```
[DisplayName("Shipment Number")]
[Required]
public string ShipmentNumber          { get; set; }
```

My View looks like this:

```
<div class="col-sm-8">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ShipmentNumber, new {@class = "form-control", @maxlength = "8", @title = "Maximum length is 8"})
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ShipmentNumber)
</div>
```

Oh, i also added these in $function:

```
$("form").kendoValidator();

$.validator.setDefaults({
       ignore: ""
 });
```

When i leave the textbox blank and submit the form, the form gets submitted without showing the error message i.e. 'The Shipment Number is required!'.
P.S: I also tried DataAnnotation:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "ShipmentNumber Is Required")]
```

Does anyone know how i can achieve this?

**Update:**
This fixed it:
Changes in Razor code to make textbox required and added required error message.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ShipmentNumber, new {@class = "form-control", @maxlength = "8", @title = "Maximum length is 8", data_required_msg = "Shipment Number is required!", required = "required" })
```

In button submit code in javascript, did this:

```
var validator = $(".form-horizontal").kendoValidator().data("kendoValidator");
if (validator.validate()) {
  //code that needs to be executed if it is valid
}
```

Note: I also got rid of data annotation from modal class, @Html.ValidationMessageFor and $("form").kendoValidator code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try forcing the validation when you click your button:

```
// Validate the input when the Save button is clicked
$("#save").on("click", function() {
    if (validator.validate()) {
        // If the form is valid, the Validator will return true
        save();
    }
});
```

or

```
$("form").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (validator.validate()) {
        status.text("Hooray! Your tickets has been booked!")
              .removeClass("invalid")
              .addClass("valid");
    } else {
        status.text("Oops! There is invalid data in the form.")
              .removeClass("valid")
              .addClass("invalid");
    }
});
```

See http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/validator/overview

Comment: Steve, it seems to be working however it shows 'tooltip' message i.e 'Maximum length is 8' instead of data annotation error message. Any idea why?

Comment: That's coming from your title htmlattribute on the TextBoxFor.

Comment: i understand that but i need that to show tooltip when user hovers over the textbox.

Comment: Oh, you're seeing that message in the validation control, not as a tooltip?

Comment: yupe, i am seeing 'Maximum length is 8' instead of one from Data Annotation error message.

Comment: Yeah, the kendo validation messages are tooltips so that's probably a conflict. Off the top of my head you might be able to use a kendotooltip() or move the tooltip to an enclosing tag?

Comment: This looks similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29620016/how-to-stop-multiple-kendo-tooltips-appearing-for-the-same-element-during-valida

Comment: Steve, made few changes and it fixed it. Updated original quesiton to include all the changes. Thanks :)